# После добавления второго языка на страницу через <div class="ru/en">, навигационное меню не корректно подсвечивается при навигации

Tags: css, анимация

Здравствуйте! Я новичок в создании сайтов, так что не судите строго. Шаблон использую Larx. проблема была в добавлении языка на страницу с условием мгновенной смены текста страницы при нажатии на кнопку RU/EN. решил ее так: часть текста обозначил как div class="ru", вторую как "en", скачал готовый скрипт, который меняет текст заголовка/страницы при нажатии на RU/EN. да, держать два текста на одной странице не камельфо, но в моем случае не принципиально. Проблема в том, что когда скроллишь страницу - навигационная панель должна показывать активный раздел по якорной ссылке, но этот активный раздел постоянно меняется, то есть анимация некорректно стала работать в совокупности с div class="ru/en". навигационная панель далее:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                    <div class="ru" lang="ru">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Главная</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">Услуги</a></li>                                                                            
                            <li><a href="#projects">Портфолио</a></li>                    
                            <li><a href="#services">Состав проекта</a></li>
                            <!----<li><a href="#blog">Мебель</a></li>     
                            <li><a href="#blog2">Материалы</a></li> ---->
                            <li><a href="#footer">Контакты</a></li>  
                            <li><a href="tel:">+7 988 966 2519</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="en" lang="en">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">Services</a></li>                                                                            
                            <li><a href="#projects">Portfolio</a></li>                    
                        <!----  <li><a href="#services">Composition of the project</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#blog">Furniture</a></li>     
                            <li><a href="#blog2">Materials</a></li> ---->
                            <li><a href="#footer">Contacts</a></li>  
                            <li><a href="tel:">+7 988 966 2519</a></li>                 
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

скрипт обработки сменщика языка прикрепляю:
              
  (function(){

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var switcherRU = document.getElementById('switcher-ru');
var switcherEN = document.getElementById('switcher-en');

// Заранее считаем срок хранения кук
var expires = new Date();
expires.setDate(expires.getDate() + 366);
expires.toUTCString();

// Русский и английский заголовки
var titleRU = document.getElementById('title-ru');
var titleEN = document.getElementById('title-en');
var title = {
  ru: titleRU.getAttribute('content'),
  en: titleEN.getAttribute('content')
}

var switchLang = function() {
  var lang = this.id
  lang = lang.replace('switcher-', '');

  // Меняем класс для BODY
  body.className = lang;

  // Записываем куки
  document.cookie = [
    'lang=' + lang
    ,'; expires=' + expires // используем expires, max-age не поддерживается в ИЕ
    ,'; path=/'
    ,'; domain=' + document.location.host
  ].join('');
  document.title = title[lang];
}

switcherRU.onclick = switchLang;
switcherEN.onclick = switchLang;
```

})();

1) Пожалуйста, скажите, почему у меня началась эта проблема
2) может есть другой способ реализовать двуязычие новичку? повторяю, новичку, я слаб в создании сайтов
Буду очень рад, если найдется решение, спасибо!